# Duda con Apache2 dns

Tags: ubuntu, apache, dns

Hola tenia una duda...

No se como explicarlo bien pero por ejemplo si alguien tiene el dominio pepe.com y pone un dns a mi ip de la vps. Apache2 le muestra una de las paginas que tengo en /var/www/

Quisiera saber si hay una forma de "limitar" eso, que otros dominios no puedan ver mis paginas.

Espero haberme explicado

Comment: Quizás deberias poner esta consulta en [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) (en inglés).  En todo caso te recomiendo que busques en tu configuración de apache el virtualhost correspondiente a tu IP, also así como `<VirtualHost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx>` o bien `<VirtualHost *>` para ver donde apunta, y allí donde este apuntando editar o crear el archivo `.htaccess` correspondiente y en el aplicar reglas `rewrite` que no permititan el surfeo al sitio web alojado si `%{HTTP_HOST}` no contiene su nombre correcto.